# onItemClickListener doesn't listen. android:focusable="false" & android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" are already set

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

onItemClick doesn't work. What's cause?
I just wanna get Second, GreetingActivity by clicking on ListView's items

```
lvData.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Log.d(TAG, "itemClick: position = " + position + ", id = " + id);
          String selectedFromList =(String) (lvData.getItemAtPosition(position));
          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GreetingActivity.class);
          intent.putExtra("item_name", selectedFromList);
          startActivity(intent);
        } 
      });
```

Here is item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.28"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="kg.aykut.speak_kyrgyz.MainActivity" >
```

> Here is my listview

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"

    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.28"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: have tried android:focusableInTouchMode="false", nothing changed.

Comment: <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="kg.aykut.speak_kyrgyz.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>